# Delphi package conflicts with itself in a subpackage

Tags: git, delphi, package

I inherited a Delphi project where most of things are done in packages that exist in separate Git repositories (git submodules). It would not be so bad if it was no subpackages (git sub-submodules).

And the worst is that one git submodule is used in a main project and as a submodule for a submodule:

```
MainProject -> Submodule1
MainProject -> Submodule2 -> Submodule1
MainProject -> Submodule3 -> Submodule1
```

Now I have a name conflict between three units in Submodule1.

What could I do? How could I make Delphi ignore the units that exist in subpackages and make it use only the units from the first nesting level?

Comment: You can't. Just make sure that there are no naming conflicts, either by ensuring that each unit exists in one package only, or by renaming units until the naming conflicts are solved.

Comment: No such thing as a sub-package. You need to read up and gain a better understanding of this area.

Comment: Pay attention to [this warning](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Berlin/en/X1033_Unit_'%25s'_implicitly_imported_into_package_'%25s'_(Delphi))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no "subpackages". Each package is a package on its own. But let's assume you have the following setup:

- package1

  - unit1A
  - unit1B
  - unit1C
- package2

  - unit2A uses unit1A
  - unit2B uses unitX
- package3

  - unit3A uses unit1B
  - unit3B uses unitX

If any of `unit2A`, `unit2B`, `unit3A`, or `unit3B` needs to use a unit from `package1`, then that *package* should be in the `requires` section of `package2` or `package3`, but the units `unit1A`, `unit1B` or `unit1C` should ***not*** be in the `contains` section of these packages, nor should they be silently included — you get a message if that happens.

In the setup above, if `unitX` is not in a package in the `requires` section of `package1` and `package2`, it gets silently included. If that happens in more than one package, you have a naming conflict. So you either include it in `package2` and require `package2` from `package3` too, or you put it into a package of its own.

So whatever you do:

- **Each unit** (let's call it A) **can only be in one single package at once**.
- If another unit (say, Z) needs to use it (A), the package for that unit (Z) must *reference* (in the `requires` section) the *package* that contains unit A. **Unit A should not be included directly**.

If there still are naming conflicts, rename the units until each name is unique.